# filter greater (or lower) than as function parameter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an dplyr code like this

```
data <- load_data(country = "us") %>%
    filter(number > 1)
```

I'd like to create function from this call like this

```
test <- function(country_code = "us") {
   data <- load_data(country = country_code) %>%
        filter(number > 1)
}
```

But I'd like to add even parameter for that number filter. Usually I do it same way as country_code. But I want be able to call even number = 0 or number is less than 1 and so on.

So the question is how to deal with that grater (less/equal) symbol in function call?

Resould shoud be something like `test <- function(country_code = "us", number > 0)` or

```
test <- function(country_code = "us", number <= -10)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters to the filter function using the `...` notation.

Example:

```
test <- function(path, country_code = "us", ...) {
   read_csv(path) %>%
        filter(...)
}

test('somepath', country_code = "us", number <= -10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer by @JohannesNE. Here is another option using `match.fun` and `rlang::sym`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

test <- function(country_code = "us", op, col, value) {
    load_data(country = country_code) %>%
      filter(match.fun(op)(!!sym(col), value))
}
```

Here, we pass operator, column and value to compare separately in the function.

You can then call `test` as

```
test("us", "<=", "number", -10)
```

Testing it on `mtcars`

```
test <- function(op, col, value) {
   mtcars %>% filter(match.fun(op)(!!sym(col), value)) 
}

test("==", "cyl", 6)

#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1
#4 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1
#5 19.2   6  168 123 3.92 3.44 18.3  1  0    4    4
#6 17.8   6  168 123 3.92 3.44 18.9  1  0    4    4
#7 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we can get the expression with `enexpr` and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
test <- function(path, country_code = "us", expr1) {

     expr1 <- rlang::enexpr(expr1)
     load_data(country = country_code) %>%
         filter(!! expr1)

    }
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
test <- function(data,  expr1) {
   expr1 <- rlang::enexpr(expr1)
   data %>%
       filter(!! expr1)


}

test(mtcars, vs == 1)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#2  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#3  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#4  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#5  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#6  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#7  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#8  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#9  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#10 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#11 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#12 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#13 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#14 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```